# Normals create black spaces in Cycles but work fine in other rendering engines

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals, normal-map

I am relatively new to blender and recently learned to bake normal maps. I did this and it worked fine (It looks great in Eevee) up until I switched to Cycles. Now, either the normal gets misaligned, or the whole thing turns black, or just parts of it turn black like the picture. Not sure why Eevee likes my normal but cycles doesn't. Any help would be awesome!
[image: Viewport, Normals, and Node Editor]

Comment: So, messed around a bit and I guess it randomly started working? Not sure why. I'd still love feedback about what may have caused this problem and how to fix it if it comes back :/

Comment: Normal map node strength too high?

Comment: you need a 32 Bit-Float image, maybe it's the problem? Maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/